# How to get notified with any new issue created in YouTrack?

Tags: youtrack

We have like 10 projects in our YouTrack installation. I want a new team colleague to get notified everytime a new issue is created for one specific project.

Is there something like project manager role? Or do I have to make a custom search and subscribe to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the both options are possible.

You can make your college a project lead. To do this you should go to this particular project settings (/editProject/) and choose this person in `Project lead` dropdown. In this case a special saved search `Unassigned in <Project>` is created and the person is subscribed to notifications about created issues in this search.

However, the disadvantage of this solution is that you can have only one project lead per project. So, if you want several people to get such notifications, you can make a similar saved search (with a search line like `project: <id> #Unassigned`) and subscribe each user for this search - go to their profiles, select `Filters and Notifications` tab, find this saved search in saved searches list and check corresponding `on issue created` checkbox.